# Why do I have to reseed the random generator when using iterators?

Tags: c++, random, stl-algorithm

My goal is to fill each element of each vector of a vector of vectors with a random value. Please consider to following code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <vector>


typedef std::vector<int> IntVect;
typedef std::vector<IntVect> Grid;


void fillRandom(Grid& grid, int lo, int hi);


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    Grid grid { Grid(5, IntVect (5)) };

    fillRandom(grid, 0, 10);

    for (auto& row : grid) {
        for (auto& i : row) {
            std::cout << i << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
// fillRandom v1
void fillRandom(Grid& grid, int lo, int hi) {

    // Init Random engine
    std::random_device rnd_device;
    std::mt19937 generator { rnd_device() };
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distr(lo, hi);
    auto dice = std::bind(distr, generator);

    Grid::iterator i { grid.begin() };
    for (; i != grid.end(); ++i) {
        std::generate(i->begin(), i->end(), dice);
        generator.seed(rnd_device());              // reseed
        dice = std::bind(distr, generator);
    }
    return;
}
```

In `fillRandom` I have to reseed the generator for each element of `grid`. Otherwise the output will be the same for each element of `grid`, like:

```
7 5 8 1 9 
7 5 8 1 9 
7 5 8 1 9 
7 5 8 1 9 
7 5 8 1 9
```

. However, if I change `fillRandom` to:

```
// fillRandom v2
void fillRandom(Grid& grid, int lo, int hi) {

    // Init Random engine as above

    for (auto& row : grid)
        for (auto& i : row)
            i = dice();
    return;
}
```

I get the expected result without reseeding the generator for each `vector`of `grid`.

In the second version of `fillRandom` `dice()` is called for each element of each vector, resulting in a `grid` filled with random values. However, the first version should do exactly the same. But it obviously does not. What's the difference here?

Why do I have to reseed the random generator for every vector when I use `std::generate` and an iterator? Could you please help me to understand this behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line `std::generate(i->begin(), i->end(), dice);` takes `dice` by value, creating a copy of it. This also copies the binded arguments. This results in you copying the same generator and distribution each time, without changing the original states. Each iteration begins with the same state.

In the second example, where you simply call `dice` in a loop, you are causing the single instances of generator and distribution to produce values, advance their internal state as a consequence, and leading to different values on the next iteration.

Try it with a lamdba instead.

```
// fillRandom v1
void fillRandom(Grid& grid, int lo, int hi) {

    // Init Random engine
    std::random_device rnd_device;
    std::mt19937 generator{ rnd_device() };
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distr(lo, hi);
    auto dice = [&generator, &distr]() { return distr(generator); };

    Grid::iterator i{ grid.begin() };
    for (; i != grid.end(); ++i) {
        std::generate(i->begin(), i->end(), dice);
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Instead of a lambda this also works and is more concise: `auto dice = std::bind(distr, std::ref(generator));`